# What does it mean when a question is grayed out?

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags

I cannot correlate with closure, negative votes, no answers, or any common thread between questions that are grayed out, and those that are not.  One can still open them, and answer or comment at will.

Why do some questions have a different appearance?

Comment: does it have a tag that you've ignored?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In a list of search results? On the front page of a site?

Comment: In Aviation Stack Exchange:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: And it would seem I made the same mistake in accidently ignoring a tag!  Thanks.